# Postgres function works in pgAdmin but not via JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc, jaro-winkler

I have installed the PostgreSQL pg_simialrity extension as described [here](https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity) so that I can use the jarowinkler function. The function works perfectly in pgAdmin but not via Spring JDBC. When executed via JDBC this error is reported

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jarowinkler(text, text) does not exist
```

Does anyone know what needs to be done to fix this problem? I am using PostgreSQL 14.0, Java 8, Spring JDBC 4.3.25.RELEASE and PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.23

Thanks.

Comment: 1) You are not connecting to same database. 2) Your are connecting to same database, but the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) is set different for the connection and the function is not being found.  Try schema qualifying function name.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I am connecting to the same database. Also as this function is an extension should it not be available to all schemas?

Comment: 1) The `search_path` is independent of the extension creation process and I would be wary of any extension that tried to modify it as `search_path` is a security feature. 2) In `psql` do `\df *.jarowinkler` to find where the function is installed.